# Facing Too many SOQL queries: 101 exception, anything wrong?

Tags: apex, soql

I am facing 101 SOQL Limit exception here, I tried to keep this out of loop, any idea why is this occurring?

```
template = (String) mapofDataBlock.get('template');

mk2021md__mdt dataBlockTemplate = getTemplate(template);


mk2021md__mdt getTemplate(string templateLabel) {
        mk2021md__mdt template = new mk2021md__mdt ();
        list<mk2021md__mdt> templateList = [SELECT field1__c, field2__c, Header__c, Body__c, Footer__c, fieldx__c, Zeroes__c FROM mk2021md__mdt WHERE Label=:templateLabel];
        if (templateList.size() != 1) {
            errorFlag = true;
            debugInfo += 'Error reading ' + templateLabel + ' metadata record.<br>';
            errorText += 'Error reading ' + templateLabel + ' metadata record. ';
        }
        else {
            template = templateList[0];
        } 
        //System.Debug('1.Number of Queries used in this apex code so far: ' + Limits.getQueries());
        return(template);
    }
```

Comment: I think you must be calling getTemplate in a loop?

Comment: no it's a separate function

Comment: Well, it is clear this error doesn't come from the code you have posted. There's something missing.

Comment: This is only the code where the 101st query is issued. You should check the code of the whole transaction and, if there are dml, you should check triggers and flow too.

Comment: After using trace logs, I can see it is occurring after the SOQL only

09:17:38.573 (8772414201)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[222]|Aggregations:0|SELECT field1__c, field2__c, Header__c, Body__c, Footer__c, fieldx__c, Zeroes__c FROM mk2021md__mdt WHERE Label=:templateLabel
09:17:38.573 (8772587921)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[222]|System.LimitException: H165nsights:Too many SOQL queries: 101
09:17:38.573 (8772871209)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[222]|Bytes:41

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving this error because this code block is in a for loop or in a method that is being called in a for loop. If that's not the case, check your stack trace and debug logs for other classes or processes that can call/access this code block.